# How to show location permissions settings

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, location-services

How to show the location permission pop up with an allow and a deny button?

I have function that receives the location, but now I need to go to the settings by myself and turn the location on.

I want that when the User opens the fragment, the location pop up gets shown.

This is the code I currently have:

**LocationFinder class:**

```
public class LocationFinder extends Service implements LocationListener {

    Context context;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 200 * 10 * 1; // 2 seconds

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public LocationFinder(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
                // Log.e("Network-GPS", "Disable");
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    // Log.e("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                } else
                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            //Log.e("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

**Fragment that shows location:**

```
public class GarageFragment extends Fragment {

    LocationFinder finder;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_garage, container, false);
        getLocation();
        return view;


    }

    public void getLocation() {
        double longitude = 0.0;
        double latitude = 0.0;
        finder = new LocationFinder(getContext());
        if (finder.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = finder.getLatitude();
            longitude = finder.getLongitude();
//            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "lat-lng " + latitude + "--" + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            finder.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), addresses.get(0).getLocality(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code  to check your permission

```
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activity.this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity.this, PERMISSIONS, 600);
        } else {
            // your code
        }
```

add in your resultActivity

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    Log.v("requestCode", "requestCode=" + requestCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 600:
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //allowed

            } else {
                //set to never ask again
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 700);
            }
            break;

        case 700:
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //allowed

            } else {
                //set to never ask again
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 700);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing Location permission popup and turning location on are two different things.
You still have to go to setting to turn location on (if it's off), while permission is just allowing your app to use the location when it's on.

To get permission you can use this method `RunTimePermissions.verifyStoragePermissions(getActivity());`

```
public class RunTimePermissions {



// Storage Permissions variables
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 6361;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS = { 
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
};



//persmission method.
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have read or write permission 
    int locationPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION); 

    if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS,
                REQUEST_CODE
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in manifests:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Add in your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   String[] locationPermissions= {"android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION","android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, locationPermissions, 121);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);        
         }
}
```

Comment: This is a great first answer!  To make it better, try to add some explanation as to why this works, ideally with some documentation to support it.